# Optional Binding on Implicitly Unwrapped Optional

Tags: swift, option-type

Swift Programming Guide says "You can also use an implicitly unwrapped optional with optional binding, to check and unwrap its value in a single statement".  Why do you need to use optional binding when the value is already unwrapped? Does option binding unwrap it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling an implicitly unwrapped is the same as calling a regular optional with ! after it. It can still hold a nil value and calling it when it's nil will result in a runtime error, so you use the if let optional binding if you aren't sure if it is nil or not.

```
var myOptional: Int! = nil

10 + myOptional //runtime error

if let myUnwrapped = myOptional{
    10 + myOptional //safe
}
```

Comment: Just calling the optional like the second line of code automatically unwraps the optional nil or not. The if let checks, then unwraps.

Comment: So optional binding essential unwraps it once more? In this case could you skip if let myUnwrapped and just check if myOptional since you are not using myUnwrapped?

Comment: It's just a more safe way of unwrapping

Comment: @Boon you can also do `if let _ = myOptional { ... }` since you don't plan to use myUnwrapped

Answer (score 2):

> Why do you need to use optional a binding when the value is already
>   unwrapped

It is *not* already unwrapped. An implicitly unwrapped optional is just an optional. It implicitly unwraps when used in *certain expressions* (postfix expressions, the same expressions where optional binding has an effect). But otherwise, it's just an optional, not unwrapped. You can use optional binding with it like with other optionals.