# Why use optional binding?

Tags: swift, optional-binding

I am aware that this question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481836/optional-binding-on-implicitly-unwrapped-optional), but it only partially answers my question and I cannot comment on the answer so I'm forced to post here.

What is the difference between optional binding and just simply using ?. My understanding is when you use ? to unwrap a variable, if it contains a nil value then the code in which it is used isn't run. (Please correct me if this is not the case.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You use [optional binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID333) (`if let`) if you have a block of code that you only want to run if the variable is not `nil`.

You use [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID245) (the `?`) only when accessing the properties/methods of an optional variable.

But there are situations where optional chaining is not possible (i.e. you're not accessing a property/method of the optional variable, but rather using that variable for other purposes). For example

```
// let's assume `data` is a `NSData?` optional

if let imageData = data {
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)

    // now do something with `image`
}
```

We do this because in this context, we can't use optional chaining, and using forced unwrapping (e.g. `let image = UIImage(data: data!)`) would crash if `data` was `nil`.